# калькулятор в одну строку

Tags: java

что нужно написать в этот код, чтобы выражение считалось в одной строке?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static String calc(String input) {
        return input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calc("1 + 1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: А сейчас что не так?

Comment: метод строку возвращает а строка не складывается

Comment: в одну строку тут не написать

Comment: мне нужно написать выражение в одну строку и оно должно сложиться

Comment: ну или выполнятся другие операции в зависимости от написание строки

Comment: Разбивай строку на символы, через switch/case определяй какой символ посередине и делай операцию с двумя другими в зависимости от этого символа

Comment: а можешь показать как разбить строку?

Comment: https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2907-metod-split-v-java-delim-stroku-na-chasti

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что при сложении строк образуется 3-я строка, а значение чисел не учитывается, тут нужно использовать int, это переменная в которой находятся целые числа

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);  //считываю значение с консоли, например: 1+213
    
    public static int calc(String input) {
        String[] result = input.split("\\+");//из строки беру 1 и 2 число, разделитель: "+", так как он расположен между числами
        return Integer.parseInt(result[0]) + Integer.parseInt(result[1]); //возвращаю результат сложения
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calc(s.nextLine())); //выполняю код calc(), передавая значение того, что ввёл пользователь в консоли
    }
}
```